# Obtain word before/after a character with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

This is supposed to be easy using capturing groups, but I am not getting the correct words. I have been using the following:

```
#Before
print(re.sub(r'\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b(?=\.?\s*(\&|\-|and))',r'\1','A. & B.',flags=re.IGNORECASE))
A. & B.

#After
print(re.sub(r'(\&|\-|and)\s*\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b',r'\2','A. & B.',flags=re.IGNORECASE))
A. B.
```

The string can be one of the following:

```
A. - B.
A.-B.
A. & B.
A.&B.
A. AND B.
```

The idea is to get the word before/after of `ampersand| hyphen | and` I divided in two regex to get both words. In this example, before would get just `A` and the after `B`.

Why the capturing groups are not printing `A` and `B` in the previous examples?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try prepending an `r` like `r'\1'`

Comment: What are your patterns meant to do? What do you want to achieve? If you want to extract substrings, why use `re.sub`? When using `re.sub` with flags, always pass them with `flags=...` to avoid any other issues.

Comment: I'd like to get the word before `&` and after. Then, the first regex should return just `A` and the second regex should give just `B`. It is fairly simple, but I have not been able to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

The string `'\1'` is octal for the decimal value 1 or 0x01 hex.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b(?=\.?\s*(\&|\-|and))','\1','A. & B.',re.IGNORECASE)
'\x01. & B.'
```

Regex needs backreferences to be escaped.

Either of these replacement strings refer to capture group 1
`'\\r'`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b(?=\.?\s*(\&|\-|and))','\\1','A. & B.',re.IGNORECASE)
'A. & B.'
```

Or,

`r'\1'`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b(?=\.?\s*(\&|\-|and))',r'\1','A. & B.',re.IGNORECASE)
'A. & B.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.search()` instead and group the desired words before and after one of the options `&,-,and`:

```
text = re.search('(\w+)\.+\s*[\&*\-*AND*and*]*\s*(\w+)\.+', 'A. & B.')
print (text.groups())
```